# Set difference between 2 variables in a string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 variables like so

```
bigger="a b c d e"
smaller="c a b"
```

Is there a way to get the set difference (i.e. d and e) in a bash script?

Order isn't important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) program to get the difference between two sets of values. It requires sorted input, so you have to pipe the values to `sort`. Since they require each item to be on a separate line, you should first translate the spaces to newlines. And you can use process substitution and here-strings to feed the strings to the program.

```
diff=$(comm -23 <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$bigger" | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$smaller" | sort))
```

Comment: Would this be faster than the for loop example posted below?

Comment: Tip: if you're work with arrays instead of space-deliimted strings, you want e.g. `printf '%s\n' "${bigger[@]}"` instead of e.g. `tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$bigger"`. This handles quoting properly.

Answer (score 2):

One way to emulate sets is with the keys of associative arrays.  Here, we create an associative array whose keys match `$bigger` and then remove any key which appears in `$smaller`:

```
bigger="a b c d e"
smaller="c a b"
declare -A a
for i in $bigger
do
    a["$i"]=1
done
for i in $smaller
do
    unset a["$i"]
done

echo "Difference is ${!a[*]}"
```

The above code produces the output:

```
Difference is d e
```

#### Handling of duplicates

Since the OP asked for a "set difference," this approach treats *bigger* and *smaller* as sets: duplicate entries are ignored/removed.  Thus, the set difference will never duplicate items.  For example, suppose bigger has duplicate entries for `c` and `d`:

```
$ bigger="a b c d e c d"
$ smaller="c a b"
$ for i in $bigger; do a["$i"]=1; done
$ for i in $smaller; do unset a["$i"]; done
$  echo "Difference is ${!a[*]}"
Difference is e d

$ echo "Difference is ${!a[*]}"
Difference is e d
```

Duplicates have been removed.

Comment: Nice solution, although it doesn't handle duplicates in the bigger array.

Comment: @Noldorin Maybe.  It depends on what is meant by "handle."  The OP asks for a "set difference" and this solution handles `$bigger` like a set: duplicates are removed.  I added a section to the end of the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Using variable substitution

```
$ echo ${bigger//[${smaller// /}]/}
d e
```

Or

```
$ echo ${bigger//[$smaller]/}
de
```